# Is getting hit by Perishables/Food worse?

Tags: nichijou

In *Nichijou* episode one, Yuuko gets hit by a *Kokeshi*, and then by an *Akabeko* on her head. She says that it could've been worse if she were struck by a Perishable, before actually getting hit on the head with a piece of Salmon.

I'm not sure if I get this. Why would it be worse? Why would she even say that? Is this some cultural reference, or am I just reading too much into this?

> I should be glad nothing perishable struck me. It could have been worse.

[image: a]
[image: b]

Comment: I'm _pretty sure_ the humour is _supposed_ to have an absurdity factor (that that's "how the joke works"): After Yuuko's "at least it wasn't..." comment, (just like it happened for you (and also for me)) the viewer probably thinks to themselves "... okay, but why on earth would that even happen? Why would one's mind even go there?" and then it happens. The absurdity comes from the fact that there's no logic to it. The odds of it happening in the real world are virtualy zero. And then it happens. Almost like that universe wanted to spite her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perishables are worse because kokeshi is a solid wooden item and does not stain or make your hair dirty, whereas salmon would smell, and soil the hair. The joke is in the fact that she mentions the possibility of something like salmon falling on her head right before it happens. She mentions that because it is very unlikely that any object would fall from the sky and hit one's head, and it happens twice in a row, which is supposed to add to comic effect.

Comment: After this Salmon strike, the next scene in continuation shows Nano's fist rocketing towards Yukko's head! (Which is probably the most unlikely event to ever happen!)  xD